# Gmail warns of " unusual activity" but no other IP addresses but my own have been logged by them

Tags: gmail, security

This morning I tried to log in to my Gmail account only to discover it was locked due to "unusual activity detected".

It gave me the option to verify my account via phone, which I did, and I got control of the account again.

After looking up what could trigger unusual activity, I learned I can see the details of the most recent activity on my account via IP addresses that have logged in. All of the addresses belong to me and nothing is out of the ordinary at all in the last 2 days. They only locked it this morning, because only a 4 hours earlier I accessed it just fine.

Does this mean perhaps someone had several failed entries trying to invade my account?
Has anyone else had this issue before?

Comment: It seems like that - did you recently changed your password?

Comment: I changed my password only after I got the warning from Gmail.

Comment: This has happened to me today. I was forced to give my phone number to Google in order to re-enable my account, and was forced to change my password. The activity log doesn't show any other IP address than mine, and the user agent was the same. Google failed to notify me what was supposed to be the "unusual activity". They redirected me to a common help-page that lists several causes but I don't know which one, if any, was the cause of their current actions. How can I get this information from them?