# How to get specific information on "unusual activity" on Gmail from Google?

Tags: gmail

This has happened to me today. I was forced to give my phone number to Google in order to re-enable my account, and was forced to change my password. The activity log doesn't show any other IP address than mine, and the user agent was the same. Google failed to notify me what was supposed to be the "unusual activity". They redirected me to a common help-page that lists several causes but I don't know which one, if any, was the cause of their current actions.

What happened to me is basically the same as with question [Gmail warns of " unusual activity" but no other IP addresses but my own have been logged by them](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30786/gmail-warns-of-unusual-activity-but-no-other-ip-addresses-but-my-own-have-bee)
. However my goal is different from that question, because I seek a way to get the actual detailed and specific information from Google.

According to Gmail TOS, do I have the right to demand this information from Google? Are they required to give the specific details to me?

Where and how can I ask Google to give me the very specific data on supposedly unusual activity?

I am suspicious because there doesn't seem to be any unusual activity. Actually it looked like they were just interested in my phone number and pushed me to enter it. Specific data could prove otherwise, so I'm interested how to get it.

Comment: It could very well have been someone attempting, and failing, to log into your account. They probably wouldn't have recorded that IP address. Or, perhaps, someone was attempting a man-in-the-middle attack. Have you been using any public wifi lately? I really doubt that they would be forthcoming with this information, because such information would be useful to the bad guys in bypassing their checks. Your bank doesn't give you the details of their fraud protection algorithms when they tell you there has been suspicious activity on one of your credit cards.

Comment: @AlEverett thanks, I have not used public wifi, I was working at my workplace on ethernet, that I generally trust as a secure network (secured for about 500 workers). My computer is win7 with an updated and active NOD32.